# Embed wordpress admin inside an iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed my wordpress admin in an iframe and it's not working.
I tried many solutions such as removing those lines:

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need use remove_action function:

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```