# WordPress Login inside an iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to build a mobile app out of a wordpress site, and I've got the site loading via an iframe. Everything is working nicely so far, but I'm getting this error when I go to the login page:

"Refused to display 'http://example.com/wp-login.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

I've done some Googling and I found another person who had a similar problem here - [Embed wordpress admin inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425222/embed-wordpress-admin-inside-an-iframe/41679270). The solution was to use

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

But I've honestly got no clue where to put that code. Some more Googling pointed me towards the “./wp-includes/default-filters.php” file, but wouldn't that get overwritten with each WP update? Where can I put that code so it doesn't get overwritten and I can load my WP login inside an iframe?

Comment: You are running into a security feature called `same-origin policy`. If there is only one page that you want to iframe, do what's listed in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182768/x-frame-options-sameorigin-blocking-iframe-on-my-domain/12192385#12192385

Comment: Where would I put that code for it to effect the wp-login page?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :) Thanks to this post - [Can't access WordPress Dashboard in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338559/cant-access-wordpress-dashboard-in-an-iframe). The solution was to put

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

in the functions.php file. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Great you fixed it!